# Is language is more about "intent" rather than a great tool for communication?

Tags: historical-linguistics, sociolinguistics

Do you think it's fair to say Language is more about "intent" rather than a great tool for communication?

I wonder if it is a limitation of language in some way, that its so easy to miscommunicate verbally and the great need to always supplement conversations with extra visual clues to get the fuller meaning.

TBH I'm not sure that I have the right "field/category" so feel free to direct it to the right minds! :P

but was just interested in what Noam Chomsky was talking about, and would enjoy to hear other people's views to help me understand more about how we communicate.

Cheers
N
:)

On Language and Culture 
"this is described as communication. But that is very misleading, I think. There is a narrow class of uses of language where you intend to communicate"

http://www.chomsky.info/interviews/1984----.htm

Comment: Oof. This is not a bad topic (though possibly too big), but some editing is needed for clarity. The biggest issue to me is using and defining the term ‘intent’; is this even necessary, and does it simply mean ‘anything communicated not in the narrow sense mentioned below'. A more relevant quote from that might be “It doesn't have much to do with communication in a narrow sense; that is, it doesn't involve transmission of information” (this is a pretty narrow sense indeed). And it’s clearly untrue that we must always supplement conversations with visuals.

Comment: Also,’transmission of information’ still may not be limited enough (possibly ‘propositional information’?); and it should be clarified if you’re asking only about miscommunication, or about nonpropositional information conveyance (the social purposes described in the cited essay).

Comment: "Intent* is hardly well-defined . Do you mean (a) what you plan to do? (b) what you believe to be true? (c) whether you are lying? (d) what you think of your addressee? (d ...) etc? On the other hand, _communication_ is very well-defined, recognizable, measurable, and repeatable. Which one would **you** start out studying scientifically? The one that might produce some objective results or the one that would let you philosophize forever before you had to describe any real phenomena?

Comment: No.  But I appreciate Chomsky's attempt to provoke an interesting discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Chomsky made the distinction between linguistic competence and linguistic performance. Competence is the internalized knowledge possessed by a native speaker, while performance covers all other aspects of language including its production and comprehension through speech, hearing, or other modalities. According to Chomsky, only competence should be the object of linguistic inquiry.

But why? First and foremost, it just makes sense from a methodological perspective. If one believes that language is a biological faculty, one should dismiss its communicative aspect when investigating its internal structure. Do people study limbs on the basis of their ability to throw or kick footballs? Or the eyes' ability to watch movies? No. However, one may still ask whether communication was selectively advantageous in the evolution of the language faculty. This doesn't seem to be the case. [Dawkins and Krebs (1978)](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/233820851_Animal_signals_Information_or_manipulation) makes the point that communication is a type of altruism, and so if it's correct that communication was selectively advantageous, we're led to theoretical difficulties in trying to account for why this altruistic behavior emerged, and on top of that, this sheds zero light on why modern syntactic phenomena in human language is the way it is.

But [Merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(linguistics)) explains a lot and if we adopt the hypothesis that the language faculty is the result of a mutation in a single human (i.e. what I think is the ability to recursively Merge), then the widely successful generative enterprise is on solid evolutionary ground. See [Bolhuis, Tattersall, Chomsky, and Berwick (2014)](http://www.plosbiology.org/article/fetchObject.action?uri=info:doi/10.1371/journal.pbio.1001934&representation=PDF).

Comment: I don't understand Dawkins and Kreb's argument, and I can't quickly get access to the full text. Does it also apply to the evolution of other biological capacities that facilitate language, like throat shape and so on?

Comment: Communication is altruistic?  This makes no sense to me.  Our early ancestors needed to coordinate hunting in groups to bring down big game -- mammoths and such.  "Tom and Hank will circle around to the left and drive it back toward the rest of us."  Then we all get meat to last us a week.  That's not altruism.